# Why do I get a Precision error when generating OData v4 Client Code?

Tags: c#, odata

I'm using OData v4 Client Code Generator to convert a customer OData v4 metadata to generate strongly type object so I can build LINQ query against it. However, I keep getting the below error and I've gone over Microsoft documents and google without any luck.  Have anyone run into this issue or know how can I fix it?

```
Running transformation: System.InvalidOperationException: The attribute 'Precision' was not expected in the given context
```

Below are some of the object that contains the Precision attribute:

```
 <Property Name="AssociationFee" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="13" Scale="2"/>
 <Property Name="BathroomsOneQuarter" Type="Edm.Byte" Precision="3"/>
 <Property Name="YearBuiltEffective" Type="Edm.Int16" Precision="4"/>
```